# Set synonym for Java ASM framework tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently two tags for the [ASM framework for Java](http://www.ow2.org/), the more popular [java-bytecode-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm) and the [java-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-asm) tag. I suggest making the [java-bytecode-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm) tag a synonym of the [java-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-asm) tag, despite the reverted popularity.

In my opinion, the [java-bytecode-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm) tag is unnecessarily verbose and it suggests that there is another use of the ASM framework than byte code manipulation. However, as the [java-asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-asm) tag is only in little use such that I doubt that there will ever be a *natural selection* of this synonym which is why I wanted to suggest it here.